# \itemize vs. \begin{itemize} not behaving as expected

Tags: macros, lists, itemize

I want to write a wrapper macro for an `itemize` environment.  I would like to use the `enumitem` package (though the MWE here doesn't use or need this package).  The problem is the parameters that I'm passing to the `itemize` environment may themselves be encoded inside another macro.

So for the wrapper macro, I wanted to write something like

```
\expandafter\itemize\expandafter[\anothermacro]
```

to handle this.  But I got very unexpected results.

For some reason, the following two styles to embedding an `itemize` environment in a wrapper macro don't work identically.

The first style just uses `\begin{itemize}` followed by content and then a closing `\end{itemize}`.

The second style used `\itemize` followed by content and then a closing `\enditemize`.  But in the second style, I get nested environments.  Not at what I'm expecting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_ae_itemize_clist
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Style A                                                                        
\cs_new:Npn \_ae_itemize_a:nn #1#2 
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_ae_itemize_clist { #2 }
     \begin{itemize}
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_ae_itemize_clist
      { \item ##1 }
    \end{itemize}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\aefooda}{ O{}mm }
    { \par\textbf{#2:}
      \_ae_itemize_a:nn {#1}{#3}
    }
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Style B                                                                        
\cs_new:Npn \_ae_itemize_b:nn #1#2 
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_ae_itemize_clist { #2 }
     \itemize
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_ae_itemize_clist
      { \item ##1 }
    \enditemize
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\aefoodb}{ O{}mm }
    { \par\textbf{#2:}
      \_ae_itemize_b:nn {#1}{#3}
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\textbf{Style A} works fine:
\aefooda{first}{a,b,c}

\aefooda{second}{a,b,c}

\aefooda{third}{a,b,c}

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Changing from style A to style B                                               
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\textbf{Style B} doesn't work:
\aefoodb{first}{a,b,c}

\aefoodb{second}{a,b,c}

\aefoodb{third}{a,b,c}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

I've also tried something like the following:

```
\edef\aeBeginItemize[#1]{\noexpand\begin{itemize}[#1]}
\cs_new:Npn \_ae_itemize_c:nn #1#2 
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_ae_itemize_clist { #2 }
    \aeBeginItemize[#1]
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_ae_itemize_clist
      { \item ##1 }
    \end{itemize}
  }
```

But when I try to use it, I get an error from the `enumitem` package:  it seems that `enumitem` is not longer able to process the keys correctly.

Comment: not an authoritative answer, but if you look at the definition of `\begin` in `latex.ltx` you will see that it does lots more than just launch the command that has the same name as the environment.  the side effects of that are no doubt why you see quite different behavior in the two situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itemize` needs to know the nesting level it is, so it increments (locally) a counter. Within `\begin{itemize}` and `\end{itemize}` there are `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` that keep that assignment local. You surely can emulate it by adding `\group_begin:` and `\group_end:` to your function; choose between style A or B, where I show also how you can expand the option list for `itemize`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\pagestyle{empty}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_ae_itemize_clist

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Style A                                                                        
\cs_new:Npn \_ae_itemize_a:nn #1#2 
  {
   \clist_set:Nn \l_ae_itemize_clist { #2 }
   \use:x { \exp_not:n { \begin{itemize} } [\exp_not:o {#1}] }
   \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_ae_itemize_clist { \item ##1 }
   \end{itemize}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\aefooda}{ O{}mm }
    { \par\textbf{#2:}
      \_ae_itemize_a:nn {#1}{#3}
    }
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Style B                                                                        
\cs_new:Npn \_ae_itemize_b:nn #1#2 
  {
   \group_begin:
   \clist_set:Nn \l_ae_itemize_clist { #2 }
   \use:x { \exp_not:N \itemize [ \exp_not:o { #1 } ] }
   \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_ae_itemize_clist { \item ##1 }
   \enditemize
   \group_end:
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\aefoodb}{ O{}mm }
    { \par\textbf{#2:}
      \_ae_itemize_b:nn {#1}{#3}
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\textbf{Style A} works fine:
\aefooda{first}{a,b,c}

\aefooda{second}{a,b,c}

\aefooda{third}{a,b,c}

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Changing from style A to style B                                               
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

\textbf{Style B} works too:
\aefoodb{first}{a,b,c}

\aefoodb[label=+]{second}{a,b,c}

\newcommand{\test}{label=X,font=\textbf}
\aefoodb[\test]{third}{a,b,c}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've updated my answer.  In the update there is an example of something which, on the face of it, seems kindred to what you're doing.  But it doesn't work.  Where it seems to differ is where you use `\exp_not:o`.  Why does that seem to make all the difference?

Comment: @A.Ellett The main problem is that `\aeBeginItemize` *doesn't* fully expand `#1` at call time: once the definition is made, it's unimportant whether a macro was defined with `\def` or `\edef`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that matter about `\def` and `\edef`.  That clued me in to what was going wrong with my update.  I really should have put that defining inside the definition of the macro `\_ae_itemiz_c:nn` and then define it as `\edef\aeBeginItemize{\noexpand\begin{itemize}[#1]}`

Comment: @A.Ellett No; macros like `\textbf` in `#1` would make this bomb out. There's no risk with `\exp_not:o`, because after one expansion the resulting token list is protected by `\unexpanded`.

Comment: Oops,  Then I've got a lot of refactoring to do.  I hadn't thought about that.  I've been using that `\edef` trick for a while now.

Comment: So is there a `TeX` level approach that mimics what `\exp_not:o` can do?

Comment: @A.Ellett `\unexpanded\expandafter{\cs}` will expand `\cs` once and protect the resulting token list against expansion.